# Does uninstalling ArcGIS Desktop delete all user data as well?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, installation

Where can I get my shapefiles, layers, geodatabases etc. that were created with ArcGIS 10.1 AFTER I uninstall ArcGIS for desktop 10.1?

Are the files saved in Documents folder remaining after uninstall arcgis 10.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're saved. Uninstalling ArcGIS won't delete anything from your `\Users\username\Documents\ArcGIS` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have data in different locations, they will remain. The ArcGIS uninstaller only removes things that it installed. It even keeps personal preferences.